# How to add multiple relationships to a new entity?

Tags: featuretools

I am trying to add multiple relationships simultaneously to an entityset that i created. I use the following code:

```
import featuretools as ft

data = ft.demo.load_mock_customer()
customers_df = data["customers"]
sessions_df = data["sessions"]
transactions_df = data["transactions"]

entities = {
    "customers" : (customers_df, "customer_id"),
    "sessions" : (sessions_df, "session_id", "session_start"),
    "transactions" : (transactions_df, "transaction_id", "transaction_time")}

es = ft.EntitySet('es',entities=entities)

relationships = [("sessions", "session_id", "transactions", "session_id"),
    ("customers", "customer_id", "sessions", "customer_id")]

es.add_relationships(relationships)
```

It throws `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'child_entity'`. Is this way to add multiple entities to an entityset correct (i think it is correct if i am reading the [official doc](https://readthedocs.com/projects/feature-labs-inc-featuretools/downloads/pdf/stable/) correctly) or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to `add_relationships` must be a list of relationship objects. This is how you would add the relationships to the entity set:

```py
relationships = []

parent = es["sessions"]["session_id"]
child = es["transactions"]["session_id"]
relationship = ft.Relationship(parent, child)
relationships.append(relationship)

parent = es["customers"]["customer_id"]
child = es["sessions"]["customer_id"]
relationship = ft.Relationship(parent, child)
relationships.append(relationship)

es.add_relationships(relationships)
```

As an alternative, you can directly construct an entity set with the relationships.

```py
relationships = [(
    "sessions",
    "session_id",
    "transactions",
    "session_id",
), (
    "customers",
    "customer_id",
    "sessions",
    "customer_id",
)]
```

```py
es = ft.EntitySet(
    id='es',
    entities=entities,
    relationships=relationships,
)
```

Let me know if this helps.